# Why the most disliked places on Earth are the bazaars?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, sunnah

Saw it somewhere that...."It is also stated that the most liked of places on Earth are the Masjids and the most disliked places on Earth are the bazaars."

Found it below:

http://www.ummah.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-243047.html

Why bazaars are the most disliked place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bazars are place where people buy and sell worldly goods. Though there is nothing wrong in doing business, it is place where we can easily forget about worshiping Allah in the eagerness to earn more.

> [Are] men whom neither commerce nor sale distracts from the
> remembrance of Allah and performance of prayer and giving of zakah.
> They fear a Day in which the hearts and eyes will [fearfully] turn
> about. [Quran 24:37](https://quran.com/en/24/37)

So commerce and sale should not distract a true believer from remembering and worshiping of Allah.

Another possible reason is Bazaars are place where lot of cheating can take place, like selling items not disclosing their faults, not giving full measure of items bought etc. Of course, a true believer should be honest in his business.

So business place is place where people can forget about Allah and due to chances of earning sins while doing business can be the reason it is mentioned as most disliked place.